# Visual Studio Browser Link with Parallels host OS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, parallels

I have just started using VS 2013 and i'm trying to take advantage of the new browser link feature.

I am running windows 8.1 inside a parallels VM. I am connecting to IISExpress from the Mac version of firefox...however BrowserLink doesn't see any browsers on my mac. Is there a way to make it work remotely?

It's working fine locally.

Comment: did you found out how to get this working? I'm trying to connect from a tablet to my VS and have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

To this date, it's not possible to do.

I did ask Mads Kristensen directly via Twitter and this was his response:

> No, we are trying to figure out how to deal with firewalls in a good way. Until then we've limited BL to local requests only

https://twitter.com/mkristensen/status/453202825351159808

Answer (score 0):

I found I can do it via Proxy on the Windows machine.
the VS fool that the request is from localhost.